# How to be able to distinct two objects based in a union type?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I want to implement `tryInline`, which should attempt to call a function and return two kinds of object based in the invoking's success or failure.

If the `fn` param was called successfully, `tryInline` should return:

```
{
  ok: true,
  data: <The value returned by `fn`>,
  error: null
}
```

And if `fn` throws an error, `tryInline` should return:

```
{
  ok: false,
  data: null,
  error: Error
}
```

I managed to do the following:

```
type Result<D> =
  | { ok: true; data: D; error: null }
  | { ok: false; data: null; error: Error };

function tryInline<Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  fn: Fn,
  ...args: Parameters<Fn>
): Result<ReturnType<Fn>> {
  try {
    const data = fn(...args);

    return { ok: true, data, error: null };
  } catch (error) {
    return { ok: false, data: null, error: error };
  }
}

const { ok, data, error } = tryInline((a: number, b: number) => a + b, 1, 3);

if (ok) {
  console.log(ok); // inferred type: `true` 
  console.log(data); // inferred type: `number | null`  Should be `number`
  console.log(error); // inferred type: `Error | null`  Should be `null`
}

if (!ok) {
  console.log(ok); // inferred type: `boolean`  Should be `false`
  console.log(data); // inferred type: `number | null`  Should be `null`
  console.log(error); // inferred type: `Error | null`  Should be `Error`
}
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=27#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAEQHxQLwCgooAfKAbygHsBrALimACdEIBuKAEwENgv6N2ERo0qN6AOxTIoAX0IlyVOlABmXZPDacefKJOTJBw0fQCixxrNb58KxOIDGwAJaVxDRiACS45M-EQaABi7hAAHsAQ4hzwUAAUAHRJXIwA5vD0XOIgANoAugCUeDhZIFhx8iri9CEANPJJCSnp9AAKKVwAthCRjPDB4lj4BfRwSKhocMCIjOIAKuCBIVg4ZPJMIOTyRA5u8MDavHiq4onJafAF1ttQjD0z7hQ09EwstYdc70IiYnpSVvIZFAHDwHAALeLfURFNZEIh3aazRTPVTqTTvbi8CRSL4WehQywyaxEORyfC7cT7ZHUDE6XE-WTHDY%20PwBOJxXSSToAIyE7252J5QiKuBKUAA1FBue8AIzvADMVxszhU8RoMPkFPglGQEASyEoqTi6vYAHpTVB-CpvhAOAxFvQAAavCCOqCAXg3ALI7mr2Or1BqNmK4Vyg5st4mtwlt9sgTq5vMspH0yDd7sAcjtQADKYMoKDtvKgjvjQkdPspfv1hriBJDYatNrtoFjhfMDKTUlTGezueQ%20egRY7%20DJKviAEJ1Vsdr7dZWjSbQxb61HGw7C9zKH6sp2szm81L%202oNK6y9qZwG4kHa4uIw2YxA44ghYm-gZt929wWB6%20TxXzzWzdekZ3CuzaOq2ogKMmb67r2%204thYpYyEAA)

However, I want to be able to correctly infer the types inside `if` blocks, which is not the current case.

Is there a way to fix this inference problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use destructuring **after** condition branching, since TS links type to object, not plain variables. When you destructure them, link between `ok` and `data` is lost. Furthermore, I think this is cleaner since you are destructuring what you really need.

```
const result = tryInline((a: number, b: number) => a + b, 1, 3);

if (result.ok) {
  const { data } = result;
  console.log(data); // inferred type: `number` 
}

if (!result.ok) {
  const { error } = result;
  console.log(error); // inferred type: `Error`
}
```

In case you just want to destructure without branching before, it seems more logical to me to just do `const { data, error } = tryInline(...)` and proceed with `if (data) { ... }`

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAEQHxQLwCgooAfKAbygHsBrALimACdEIBuKAEwENgv6N2ERo0qN6AOxTIoAX0IlyVOlABmXZPDacefKJOTJBw0fQCixxrNb58KxOIDGwAJaVxDRiACS45M-EQaABi7hAAHsAQ4hzwUAAUAHRJXIwA5vD0XOIgANoAugCUeDhZIFhx8iri9CEANPJJCSnp9AAKKVwAthCRjPDB4lj4BfRwSKhocMCIjOIAKuCBIVg4ZPJMIOTyRA5u8MDavHiq4onJafAF1ttQjD0z7hQ09EwstYdc70IiYnpSVvIZFAHDwHAALeLfURFNZEIh3aazRTPVTqTTvbi8CRSL4WehQywyaxEORyfC7cT7W4IFAHXAeby+fwQOJxXSSToAIyE7052K5QiKuBKUAA1FBOe8AIzvADMVxszhU8Tu42ACRoMPkFKpFExXFkx1VtOJwL2lGQEASyEoqTi+quUAA9E6oP4VN8IBwGIt6AADDncxh+qD4MlK+IAQmNqA11C1Oz2BwoBMN9JjwFNOotVptdoJjpdbvEHuEXp9kH95h+frDQA)